# Detect last element of group in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, grouping

I have an array of arrays. It is grouped by value in sub array:

```
[2  => [id=>5, group=>3],
6  => [id=>8, group=>3],
4  => [id=>1, group=>3],
2  => [id=>11,group=>2],
26 => [id=>41,group=>2],
5  => [id=>55,group=>6],]
```

in `foreach` cycle, I want to know, when the element is the last in its group. 
How can I do it without second `foreach` cycle?

Comment: Just keep track of the current group and compare it with the new one in your loop.

Comment: i don't  need last element in array. In foreach cycle, I want to know, when the element last in group. for example when pointer at 4  => [id=>1, group=>3],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the array is sorted by group and that you don't have spaces between elements of the same group.

```
$previousGroup = false;
$lastIndex = -1;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  if($previousGroup !== false && $previousGroup !== $value['group']) {
    echo $lastIndex.' is last index of the group '.$previousGroup;
  }

  //do something

  $previousGroup = $value['group'];
  $lastIndex = $key;
}
if($previousGroup !== false) {
  //handle the last group
  echo $lastIndex.' is last index of the group '.$previousGroup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    $arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,group=>"1"),
             1 => array(id=>2,group=>"2"),
             2 => array(id=>3,group=>"1")
);
$last=end($arr);
echo $last['group'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know when it is the last one without getting the next element, but you can determine when it changes so if you use that at the start of your `foreach` loop, you can take action after the last element of a group:

```
$group = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  if ($group > 0 && $value['group'] !== $group)
  {
    // start of new group, excluding the very first one
    $group = $value['group'];

    // do the things you want to do to separate the groups

  }
  ...
}
```